# source file specified as string in R

Tags: r, string, file

I want to, programmatically, source all .R files contained within a given array retrieved with the `Sys.glob()` function.

This is the code I wrote:

```
# fetch the different ETL parts
parts <- Sys.glob("scratch/*.R")

if (length(parts) > 0) {
    for (part in parts) {
        # source the ETL part
        source(part)

        # rest of code goes here
        # ...
    }
} else {
    stop("no ETL parts found (no data to process)")
}
```

The problem I have is I cannot do this or, at least, I get the following error:

```
simpleError in source(part): scratch/foo.bar.com-https.R:4:151: unexpected string constant
```

I've tried different combinations for the `source()` function like the following:

```
source(sprintf("./%s", part))
source(toString(part))
source(file = part)
source(file = sprintf("./%s", part))
source(file = toString(part))
```

No luck. As I'm globbing the contents of a directory I need to tell R to source those files. As it's a custom-tailored ETL (extract, transform and load) script, I can manually write:

```
source("scratch/foo.bar.com-https.R")
source("scratch/bar.bar.com-https.R")
source("scratch/baz.bar.com-https.R")
```

But that's dirty and right now there are 3 different extraction patterns. They could be 8, 80 or even 2000 different patterns so writing it by hand is not an option.

How can I do this?

Comment: @boski no, it doesn't work by providing a full path. the results are the same (unexpected string constant)

Comment: Are you sure that your R files have no syntax errors? It seems to be getting the file fine, but encountering an error within the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the list of files with dir and then using lapply:

For example, if your files are of the form `t1.R`, `t2.R`, etc., and are inside the path "StackOverflow" do:

```
d = dir(pattern = "^t\\d.R$", path = "StackOverflow/",  recursive = T, full.names = T)
m = lapply(d, source)
```

The option `recursive = T` will search all subdirectories, and `full.names = T` will add the path to the filenames.

If you still want to use Sys.glob(), this works too:

```
d = Sys.glob(paths = "StackOverflow/t*.R")
m = lapply(d, source)
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Keeps saying there's an unexpected string constant being provided to `source()`

Comment: It was my mistake. Your method works but I was re-sourcing a file called base.R with some basic definitions both in the script I shown to you in my post and each of the .R files being located by the `Sys.glob()` function. Thanks for the hint! :)